# How to easily search in the list of existing mappings?

Tags: key-bindings, search

From time to time I want to search on the list of my currents mappings. I search either for mapped keys *(what `/<Space>a` does?)* or for a command *(What keys are mapped on `/MyFunction()<CR>`?)*

I know that I can output these mappings with `:map` (or `:nmap`, `:vmap`, etc...) but this open a window where I can only scroll and not use search mode `/`.

So when I want to search in this list I have to use `redir` to put the result of the command in a new file, which I then open in vim and use search mode:

```
:redir > foo
:map
:redir END
:e foo
```

I feel like this workflow is not natural:

- It uses a lots of commands compared to what I want to do.
- It creates a new file that I have to delete.

So my question is **is there a more natural way to do a search in the currently mapped keys?**

I know that I could create a function which would executes these commands and a custom command to easily call the function, but I was wondering if there wouldn't be a more straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to search for a mapping uses a [plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim). But the good news is, you probably have it already.

The command is:

```
:Unite mapping -start-insert
```

... then you basically directly type your search term and narrow down the list.

---

*Without* a plugin, you can still narrow your map results by providing the prefix of the map, and its type. For example:

```
:verbose xmap <leader>
```

... will show the defined mappings only for visual mode, and which start with the leader key. You are not limited to one character there (e.g. you can use `xmap <leader>a` and so on).

Comment: I heard of this plugin before but never tried it I'll give it a try thanks! Also the second suggestion is nice but doesn't allow to do the second type of search i.e. which keys are mapped to execute this function.

Comment: Indeed - you can do that with the 1st suggestion. And 'Unite' (and its extensions) = the Swiss knife of Vim plugins :)

Comment: Ok I'll look at it closely then thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`:map`, `:imap` and friends take an argument so, instead of issuing a generic command and then filtering it you could simply issue a specific command from the get go:

```
:imap <CR>
```

Comment: That's a great way to do it thanks but as for VanLaser answer I stil have a question: this doesn't allow me to make a search on `MyFunction` to know which keys are mapped to call it.